# How to add post slug with Corcel for Laravel to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I using corcel for laravel.

```
$item = \Corcel\Model\Post::create(
            [
                'post_title' => $product['name'],
                'post_name' => Str::slug($product['name']),
                'guid' => 'http://domain/product/' . Str::slug($product['name']) . '/',
                'post_content' => $product['description'],
                'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'post_type' => 'product',

            ]
        );
```

But slug and guid don't filled. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you try to add static data?

Comment: Yes. The post is added and the slug is not.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Corcel wrong.

There are a lot of hooks called and other processes that are performed by WordPress before and after creating content, which aren't available when using Corcel. **Corcel is read-only.** If you wish to create content, I would recommend talking directly to the WordPress site using the REST API endpoints [such as this one](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post).